# Does every dependency have a "latest" version in sbt/maven?

Tags: maven, sbt

For example can I always use a "latest" version for every library as follows?

```
"com.kaala.re" %% "brain-builder-client"  % "latest"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LATEST for maven for any dependency, but it's DEPRECATED feature in maven 3.

> When you depend on a plugin or a dependency, you can use the version
>   value of LATEST or RELEASE. LATEST refers to the latest released or
>   snapshot version of a particular artifact, the most recently deployed
>   artifact in a particular repository. RELEASE refers to the last
>   non-snapshot release in the repository. In general, it is not a best
>   practice to design software which depends on a non-specific version of
>   an artifact. If you are developing software, you might want to use
>   RELEASE or LATEST as a convenience so that you don't have to update
>   version numbers when a new release of a third-party library is
>   released. When you release software, you should always make sure that
>   your project depends on specific versions to reduce the chances of
>   your build or your project being affected by a software release not
>   under your control. Use LATEST and RELEASE with caution, if at all.

Comment: I'd also add that LATEST & RELEASE can be used only for plugins. For the  rest these "versions" may or may not work depending on Nexus/Artifactory/whatever configuration and administration.